# Batch file to windows uninstall menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, elevated-privileges

How could I make a batch file add a EXE file to the uninstall menu on a windows 7 pc. I have windows 7 32 bit laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult but maybe possible.

The Registroy key of the uninstall menu:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

and there is the **reg** command in order to operate the Registory.

See also http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs

and help of the reg command from cmd.exe, like this:

```
c:\Users\User1>reg /?
```